# Need some advice on how to stream line ACCESS/EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I wrote this Access/VBA program. It works but only when I am not running other applications or few users are in the database.  I need some ideas on streamlining the code.  So it is not so system intensive.  The program basically allows a user to pick a folder and then combines all worksheets in that folder in one excel document.  My current idea is just to tell users to close all excel files when trying to run the program. Please Help:

```
Sub Excel_open()

Dim myXL As Excel.Application
Dim myXLS As Excel.Workbook
Const errExcelNotRunning = 429

On Error GoTo HandleIt
    Set myXL = GetObject(, "Excel.application")
    myXL.Visible = True
    Set myXLS = myXL.Workbooks.Add

    Call CombineWorkbooks(myXL)

HandleIt:

If Err.Number = errExcelNotRunning Then
    Set myXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End If

End Sub
Sub CombineWorkbooks(myXL)


'Macro that combines the files into one folder
    myXL.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    myXL.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim CurFile As String, dirloc As String, strNamesheet As String
    Dim DestWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Object ' allows for diffrent sheet types

    'Add select the director function

    dirloc = GetFolderName & "\" 'location of files not working want to select the file only
    CurFile = Dir(dirloc & "*.xls*")

    myXL.ScreenUpdating = False
    myXL.EnableEvents = False

    Set DestWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet)

    Do While CurFile <> vbNullString
        Dim OrigWB As Workbook
        Set OrigWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=dirloc & CurFile, ReadOnly:=True)

        'need to change a name active name is not doing it

        CurFile = Left(CurFile, 4) ' This is no longer 29

        'CurFile = Left(Left(CurFile, Len(CurFile) - 5), 29)

        For Each ws In OrigWB.Sheets
            ws.Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count)

            ' Use the name to give the sheet a name

            strNamesheet = Left((ws.Name), 25) & ";"

            If OrigWB.Sheets.Count > 1 Then
                DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count).Name = strNamesheet & CurFile ' & ws.Index
            Else
               DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count).Name = CurFile
            End If
        Next

        OrigWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        CurFile = Dir

    Loop

    myXL.DisplayAlerts = False
    DestWB.Sheets(1).Delete
    myXL.DisplayAlerts = True


    myXL.ScreenUpdating = True
    myXL.EnableEvents = True

    Set DestWB = Nothing

   Call Delete_empty_Sheets(myXL)
   Call Sort_Active_Book

   MsgBox "Done"

   'Call Xcombine_the_Matching

End Sub
Sub Delete_empty_Sheets(myXL)
'goes through all sheets and deletes

Reset_the_search:

For Each wsElement In Worksheets
    If wsElement.Range("A2") = "" And wsElement.Range("B2") = "" Then
        myXL.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsElement.Delete
        GoTo Reset_the_search
        myXL.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If
Next wsElement

End Sub



Sub Xcombine_the_Matching()
    'I think I can make the order work
    'change and transpose the array
    Dim varStart As Variant
    Dim wsCompare As Worksheet

    Dim strMatch As String


    'Dim varCompare As Variant

    Dim strVareince As String
    Dim strCurrentName As String

    'you need to build a loop to solve this problem

    For Each wsCompare In Worksheets

        strVareince = Add_Array(Application.Transpose(wsCompare.Range("A1:Z1")))

        For Each wsNompare In Worksheets

            If wsNompare.Name <> strCurrentName Then
                If strVareince = Add_Array(Application.Transpose(wsNompare.Range("A1:Z1"))) Then
                    MsgBox ("Matched with worksheet " & wsNompare.Name)
                End If

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub

Function array_to_string(x) As String
    For Z = 1 To 26
        array_to_string = array_to_string & x(Z, 1) & ";"
    Next Z

End Function

Function GetFolderName(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
    'Allows you to select the folder director that you want to combine
    Dim lCount As Long

    GetFolderName = vbNullString

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = OpenAt
        .Show
        For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(lCount)
        Next lCount
    End With
End Function

Function Add_Array(x) As String
    'turns an excel document
    For d = 1 To UBound(x)
        Add_Array = Add_Array & x(d, 1)
    Next d

End Function

Sub Read_data()

'this the

End Sub

Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
' Prompt the user as which direction they wish to
' sort the worksheets.
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There are two many things not known to allow a response.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? and what exactly is your problem?
multiple users are trying to access this function? Your first sub has errors.

Comment: We need to know exactly what is wrong. This is far too vague.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your Excel Application object into your subroutines, but not using it fully, neither are you explicitly referencing the libraries:

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks(myXL)
    Dim DestWB As Excel.Workbook ' <<<
    Set DestWB = myXL.Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet) ' <<<
End Sub
```

Run through your code and fix all of these first, then test & supply more feedback on what the precise symptoms of the problems are.